# CUDA thrust::device_vector of class | error

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

I am new to CUDA and the thrust library. I've been looking through a lot of examples and questions regarding my problem, however, I was not able to transfer a solution.

I have a class `Cell` which should contain a vector of `Tree` (another class).

This is my `Cell.h`

```
#pragma once

#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/generate.h>
#include <thrust/reduce.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>




#include "Tree.h"

class Cell {
    int idx;
    float xmid, ymid;
    float dx, dy;
    int nTrees;
    thrust::host_vector<Tree> trees;
//  thrust::device_vector<Tree> trees;         <-- this is what I want
public:
     Cell();
    Cell(int, float, float, float, float, int);
    void set(int, float, float, float, float, int);
    void add(float, float, float);
    void add(float);
    void add();
    virtual ~Cell();
    void print();
    void copyToDev();
};
```

and here is my `Tree.h`

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;



class Tree {

    float x, y, r;
    int idx;
public:
     Tree();
     Tree(float, float, float, int);
     void set(float, float, float, int);
     virtual ~Tree();
     void print();
};
```

The classes are both implemented in a file with extension `.cu`. In my `main.cu` I now want to initialize a `Cell C`. Given the code above, I am able to compile the code (using Visual Studio 2013 which I haven't used before, so that might be another problem for me). 
However, if I'm not mistaken, using `host_vector` I do not make use of my GPU. What I want is to use `device_vector` instead.

But if I compile the code with `device_vector` instead of `host_vector` I get the following error

```
    1>------ Build started: Project: WTM, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Cell.cu
1>c:\program files\nvidia gpu computing toolkit\cuda\v7.0\include\thrust\system\detail\error_category.inl(102): warning C4996: 'strerror': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strerror_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\string.h(168) : see declaration of 'strerror'
1>c:\program files\nvidia gpu computing toolkit\cuda\v7.0\include\thrust\system\cuda\detail\bulk\detail\pointer_traits.hpp(55): warning C4800: 'unsigned int' : forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning)
1>c:\users\thomas\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\wtm\wtm\cell.cu(40): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>c:\program files\nvidia gpu computing toolkit\cuda\v7.0\include\thrust\system\cuda\detail\for_each.inl(84): error C2027: use of undefined type 'thrust::detail::STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE<false>'
1>          c:\program files\nvidia gpu computing toolkit\cuda\v7.0\include\thrust\detail\for_each.inl(71) : see reference to function template instantiation 'RandomAccessIterator thrust::system::cuda::detail::for_each_n<thrust::system::cuda::detail::tag,InputIterator,Size,UnaryFunction>(thrust::system::cuda::detail::execution_policy<thrust::system::cuda::detail::tag> &,RandomAccessIterator,Size,UnaryFunction)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              RandomAccessIterator=thrust::device_ptr<Tree>
1>  ,            InputIterator=thrust::device_ptr<Tree>
1>  ,            Size=int
1>  ,            UnaryFunction=thrust::detail::allocator_traits_detail::gozer
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\nvidia gpu computing toolkit\cuda\v7.0\include\thrust\detail\allocator\destroy_range.inl(136) : see reference to function template instantiation 'InputIterator thrust::for_each_n<DerivedPolicy,Pointer,Size,thrust::detail::allocator_traits_detail::gozer>(const thrust::detail::execution_policy_base<DerivedPolicy> &,InputIterator,Size,UnaryFunction)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              InputIterator=thrust::device_ptr<Tree>
1>  ,            DerivedPolicy=thrust::system::cuda::detail::tag
1>  ,            Pointer=thrust::device_ptr<Tree>
1>  ,            Size=int
1>  ,            UnaryFunction=thrust::detail::allocator_traits_detail::gozer
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\nvidia gpu computing toolkit\cuda\v7.0\include\thrust\detail\allocator\destroy_range.inl(157) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void thrust::detail::allocator_traits_detail::destroy_range<Allocator,Pointer,Size>(Allocator &,Pointer,Size)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Allocator=thrust::device_malloc_allocator<Tree>
1>  ,            Pointer=thrust::device_ptr<Tree>
1>  ,            Size=int
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\nvidia gpu computing toolkit\cuda\v7.0\include\thrust\detail\contiguous_storage.inl(256) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void thrust::detail::destroy_range<thrust::device_malloc_allocator<T>,Base,int>(Allocator &,Pointer,Size)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=Tree
1>  ,            Base=thrust::device_ptr<Tree>
1>  ,            Allocator=thrust::device_malloc_allocator<Tree>
1>  ,            Pointer=thrust::device_ptr<Tree>
1>  ,            Size=int
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\nvidia gpu computing toolkit\cuda\v7.0\include\thrust\detail\contiguous_storage.inl(255) : while compiling class template member function 'void thrust::detail::contiguous_storage<T,Alloc>::destroy(thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<T>>,thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<T>>)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=Tree
1>  ,            Alloc=thrust::device_malloc_allocator<Tree>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\nvidia gpu computing toolkit\cuda\v7.0\include\thrust\detail\vector_base.inl(474) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void thrust::detail::contiguous_storage<T,Alloc>::destroy(thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<T>>,thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<T>>)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=Tree
1>  ,            Alloc=thrust::device_malloc_allocator<Tree>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\nvidia gpu computing toolkit\cuda\v7.0\include\thrust\detail\vector_base.inl(44) : while compiling class template member function 'thrust::detail::vector_base<T,Alloc>::vector_base(void)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=Tree
1>  ,            Alloc=thrust::device_malloc_allocator<Tree>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\nvidia gpu computing toolkit\cuda\v7.0\include\thrust\device_vector.h(67) : see reference to function template instantiation 'thrust::detail::vector_base<T,Alloc>::vector_base(void)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=Tree
1>  ,            Alloc=thrust::device_malloc_allocator<Tree>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\nvidia gpu computing toolkit\cuda\v7.0\include\thrust\device_vector.h(54) : see reference to class template instantiation 'thrust::detail::vector_base<T,Alloc>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=Tree
1>  ,            Alloc=thrust::device_malloc_allocator<Tree>
1>          ]
1>          c:\users\thomas\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\wtm\wtm\cell.h(27) : see reference to class template instantiation 'thrust::device_vector<Tree,thrust::device_malloc_allocator<T>>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=Tree
1>          ]
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I'm really not sure how to approach this. Maybe someone could guide me through this problem. Thank you in advance!

***EDIT***

As pointed out, I forgot the `main`, this is the code below, aso in a `.cu` file

```
#include "Cell.h"


int main(void)
{


    Cell D(0, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1);

    D.print();  
    return 0;
}
```

reduced to the minimal part. If further information are missing, just let me know.

Comment: are you creating a device_vector of Cell somewere?  You need to provide an MCVE.  You're asking for help with a compile error, and you haven't even shown the line of code that originates the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look into the file with the definition of `thrust::system::cuda::detail::for_each_n` like the error message is suggesting, you will find the following comment ([link to github](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/blob/master/thrust/system/cuda/detail/for_each.inl#L104-108)):

```
// we're attempting to launch a kernel, assert we're compiling with nvcc
// ========================================================================
// X Note to the user: If you've found this line due to a compiler error, X
// X you need to compile your code using nvcc, rather than g++ or cl.exe  X
// ========================================================================
```

Make sure you are really using `nvcc` to compile your program, and not merely trying to include thrust in a normal `c++` project which gets compiled with visual studio's `cl`.

Comment: Could you ellaborate how to do so in Visual Studio Nsight?

Comment: It turned out that this was the problem. However I am now only able to compile it on linux via command line, but not in VS since I don't know how to configure VS to use nvcc.