# thrust device_vector resize compilation error, don't understand why it requires .cu code

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

lets say I've got a main.cpp

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <cuda.h> 
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h> 
#include <iostream> 
int main(){
    thrust::device_vector<float> test; //compiles fine!
    std::cout << test.size() << std::endl; // compiles fine!
    test.resize(6); //Error in thrust/system/detail/generic/for_each.h "error c2338: static assert failed 'unimplemented for this system"
    return 0; 
}
```

I get the error above.  I understand what this error is trying to say, that I should be using .cu files, use the nvcc compiler, etc... but... why? Why does resize require a [kernel call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28965173/cuda-thrustdevice-vector-of-class-error).  There's no reason thrust vector can't be using the driver or runtime api here, so what gives?   There shouldn't be a kernel call associated with a simple resize of a vector right? Just a cudaMalloc, cudaFree, cudaMemcpy etc...?

Comment: I commented out the `test.resize(6);` line and still get the thrust static assert.  So I'm not able to reproduce your observation "//compiles fine!"  My understanding is that a thrust device vector requires initialization.  My understanding is the thrust designers chose to initialize device vectors using kernel calls, and they put the static assert in place to make sure that would be workable.

Comment: In the trivial case of vector initialization, its probably true that you could do the initialization with e.g. `cudaMemcpy` or `cudaMemset`. But there might be certain kinds of object initialization that require the execution of a device code constructor. That could not be handled except by a kernel call.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compile error with thrust::device\_vector of thrust::complex, possibly due to a wrong implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50974743/compile-error-with-thrustdevice-vector-of-thrustcomplex-possibly-due-to-a-w)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`device_vector`'s name is self-explaining, this is a vector for device memory and is not created for using in system memory. `std::vector` should be used instead. This is the author's decision for the default settings.

You are trying to use Thrust functionality in user mode code (C++ mode, CUDA is not enabled for .cpp code and is enabled for .cu code by default). They do not want to support this because changing the default system would be very disruptive. You might work around it:

1. Enable CUDA mode (by naming the file with the .cu extension or setting the compiler flag `-stdpar=gpu`), it will use `universal_vector` in memory of GPU.
2. Or you need to explicitly set `THRUST_DEVICE_SYSTEM` to use CPP or OMP instead of CUDA.

Comment: Your second option appears to fix the issue, while still **allowing me to use GPU constructs in host code which your tone strongly implies I shouldn't be able to do or otherwise shouldn't do**.  Again, there's no need for this.  Luckily we only use thrust as a vocab type and don't use algorithms. So the downsides of setting it to cpp do not effect us.

Comment: @Krupip what do you mean by "GPU constructs"? The second option tells Thrust that you don't want to use the GPU, but instead use e.g. OpenMP and system memory for all things called "`device`".